# ¿como mostrar en minutos el tiempo restante de una sesión usando $_SESSION + time (x*y) en PHP?

Tags: php

En la función de conectarse de mi sistema tengo la creación de dos variables de sesión para guardar el tiempo en que conecto al sistema y un tiempo de expiran, de la siguiente manera:

```
$_SESSION['inicio'] = time();
$_SESSION['expira'] = $_SESSION['inicio'] + (15*60);
```

Quisiera poder mostrar esos datos convertidos a minutos usando `echo`.

```
echo $_SESSION['inicio'];
echo "<br>";
echo $_SESSION['expira'];
```

**Como puedo convertirlo?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para mostrar el tiempo de sesión y el restante en minutos (y también segundos si quieres) podrías usar:

```
<?php
session_start();
$hora = time();
if (!isset($_SESSION['inicio']) && !isset($_SESSION['expira'])) {
  $_SESSION['inicio'] = $hora;
  $_SESSION['expira'] = $hora + (15*60);
}
$hace = $hora - $_SESSION['inicio'];
echo "<p>Inició sesión hace ". floor($hace / 60) .
  " minutos y " . ($hace % 60) . " segundos</p>";
if ($hora > $_SESSION['expira']) {
  $hace = $hora - $_SESSION['expira'];
  echo "<p>Su sesión finalizó hace ". floor($hace / 60) .
    " minutos y " . ($hace % 60) . " segundos</p>";
} else {
  $hace = $_SESSION['expira'] - $hora;
  echo "<p>Su sesión finaliza en ". floor($hace / 60) .
    " minutos y " . ($hace % 60) . " segundos</p>";
}
```

Iniciar el sistema de sesiones con `session_start()` es indispensable.

Luego compruebo si están definidas las variables de sesión o no. Si no lo están es porque es la primera vez que accedemos a la página, por lo que inicializamos la hora de inicio y expiración.

Por último calculo la diferencia entre la hora actual y la de inicio para mostrar el tiempo transcurrido (el número de segundos entre 60 son los minutos, y el resto de la división son los segundos), y si hemos sobrepasado el tiempo de fin de sesión indicamos cuánto tiempo hace que superamos el límite y si no hemos llegado calculamos el restante.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la función date()

```
$_SESSION['inicio'] = time();
$_SESSION['expira'] = $_SESSION['inicio'] + (15*60);

echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $_SESSION['inicio']);
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $_SESSION['expira']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías utilizar la función `DateTime::diff`.

**Ejemplo:**

```
<?php

    //Obtenemos el tiempo actual.
    $time = time();
    $tiempo_actual = date('Y-m-d  H:i:s', $time);

   $strStart = $tiempo_actual;
   //Tiempo de expira.
   $strEnd   = '2017-05-09 21:25';    

   //Convierte la cadena en una variable de fecha.
   $dteStart = new DateTime($strStart);
   $dteEnd   = new DateTime($strEnd);

   //Calculamos la diferencia 
   $dteDiff  = $dteStart->diff($dteEnd);    

   //Salida de data.
   print $dteDiff->format("%H:%I:%S");

?>
```

[Manual DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.diff.php)